# ASAF module redirects comment form to system/ajax#comment-cid after submission

Tags: forms, ajax, comments

I use [Asaf (ajax submit for any form)](https://www.drupal.org/project/asaf) module to Ajaxify form submissions in my website. This module works well but in comment form submission, it submits the comment then redirects the page to `system/ajax#comment-cid` which is a blank white page.

How can I solve this or is there any way out to Ajaxify comment form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [This page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2301041) I found the answer

In the `template.php` add the following code, replace `epic_ajax` with your theme name

```
// Disable the ajax redirect.
function epic_ajax_asaf_form_ajax_commands_alter(&$commands, $form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach($commands as $key => $command) {
        if ($form['#node']->nid) {
            if ($command['command'] == 'asafRedirect' || 'asafRefresh') {
                unset($commands[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
// These functions allow for subsequent saves without validation errors.
function epic_ajax_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'plan_node_form') {
        // Ensure our own validation is called first to overcome the node changed error node.module: 971
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], "epic_ajax_node_edit_validate");
    }
}
function  epic_ajax_node_edit_validate($form,&$form_state){
    // Update changed value to avoid node changed error node.module: 971
    $form_state['values']['changed'] =  $form_state['node']->changed;
}
```

you need to add this javascript code as well

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
      Drupal.behaviors.epicAjax = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('input, select').change(function() {
    $('#edit-actions .form-submit').first().trigger('mousedown');
    });
        }
      };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in to issues of that module I found there one important information which help on this issue. https://www.drupal.org/node/2277137